# Map Java Object

Tags: spring, angular, rest

I want to create a service in order to populate dropdown from database. I tried this:

Merchant Class:

```
export class Merchant {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public name: string,
    public state_raw: string,
    public users: string,
  ) {}
}
```

Merchant Service:

```
 getList(): Observable<Merchant> {
    return this.http.get<Merchant>(environment.api.urls.merchants.base, {});
  }
```

Rest Api impl:

```
@GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> get() {
        return merchantRepository
                .findAll()
                .map(mapper::toDTO)
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElseGet(() -> notFound().build());
    }
```

SQL query:

```
@Override
    public Iterable<Merchants> findAll() {
        String hql = "select e from " + Merchants.class.getName() + " e";
        TypedQuery<Merchants> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Merchants.class);
        List<Merchants> merchants = query.getResultList();
        return merchants;
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
The method map(mapper::toDTO) is undefined for the type Iterable<Merchants>
```

How should I implement properly this mapping for the response?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you meant to stream the entities.

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> get() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(merchantRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
            .map(mapper::toDTO)
            .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseGet(() -> notFound().build());
}
```

Comment: I get The method splititerator() is undefined for the type Iterable<Merchants>

Comment: @PeterPenzov what JDK are you using? It should be there.

Comment: java version "10.0.2"

Comment: @PeterPenzov sorry, it was my mistake. It's "spliterator", not "splititerator". I've edited my asnwer to remove this typo.

Comment: Now I get The method orElseGet(() -> {}) is undefined for the type Stream<ResponseEntity<MerchantDTO>>

Comment: @PeterPenzov I'm really off my game here. It was also missing a `findFirst()` call, which I just edited in to the answer

Comment: I don't why but the list in Angular is empty.

Comment: Probably because I get ResponseEntity<MerchantDTO> it should be list?